# Must i check the user input in UI and Programming and T-SQL(with check constraint) side at the same time?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, security

Or is the first two check fair enough for securing from hackers?And what about performance issues when i use check constraint in columns?

Comment: Check for what?  Valid input?  Injection attacks?

Comment: What do you mean? Constraints in sql are used to validate that the values are within a given range. It has nothing to do with preventing hackers, it has everything to do with data integrity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not have to check in all three places. However, your application and your database might be better off if you do.

Checking in the UI - especially with scripts or HTML - is very good for interactively showing the user how to correct their input. It saves a round trip to the web server, and is a performance enhancement because the user's CPU is used to run the validation code instead of the server.

Checking in the "programming" (here I believe you are referring to your business domain logic) is important if you ever want to add a new interface to your logic. For instance, if you have a well designed business layer that is consumed by a web application, later on you could also consume the same business layer with a WCF interface and have confidence that you aren't receiving invalid data.

And finally, validation rules in the database are important if you ever want to batch load data directly into the database. Perhaps a partner business or client sends you a text file that you need to load. Having the rules in place in the database will keep you from corrupting your data if the load routine has a defect.